# 1Gbps internet but drops to 1Mbps if I don't restart at least twice a day

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem, netgear-router

1Gbps internet but drops to 1Mbps if I don't restart my home network setup at least twice a day. Here's what I have:

- I have 1Gig internet connected to a Netgear Modem/Router.
- I have disabled wireless on the Netgear and only use it as a modem.
- I have connected Orbi AX4200 Tri-Band Mesh Wi-Fi 6 System routers to the modem.
- I have disabled DHCP in ORBI and use it as an Access Point (getting DHCP from the Netgear modem)

It works fine when I restart both the modem and the router but then drops all of a sudden from 1Gbps to 1Mbps. And require a restart.

Most of the time, I can't even watch a simple 1080p video on YouTube.

Any idea what is happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact model of Netgear Modem/Router you are using. Also, what do you mean when you say, “I have disabled wireless on the Netgear and only use it as a modem.” Simply disabling the wireless won’t turn the device into a modem; it will still act as router via the Ethernet connection. Maybe that is the issue? I think you need to properly set the Netgear Modem/Router to bridge mode if you are using the Orbi AX4200 as the router.

Comment: I will update the post with the exact model of the modem when I get home. What I mean by "disabled wireless on the Netgear" is that I don't use the modem's built-in Wi-Fi capability. Therefore, I have turned it off. And rather use my Orbi devices as a wireless router.

Comment: “…I don't use the modem's built-in Wi-Fi capability. Therefore, I have turned it off.” My guess based on what you describe is while you disabled WI-Fi, you did not disable the router portion of the Netgear Modem/Router. So while you cannot connect via Wi-Fi, the router on the  Netgear Modem/Router is still active and might cause confusion between the Orbi AX4200 and the Netgear Modem/Router that would choke the connection. Double-NATing and such. You need to set the Netgear Modem/Router to bridge mode so the router stuff is 100% disabled.

Comment: talk to your ISP. I've had simillar issues that were ultimately found to be periods of high signal to noise at my modem. a guy came out to test all my cabling, and replaced 6 feet of the drop from the pole to my abode, and that addressed the issue. rebooting the modem lets it go back through its signal acquisition and pairing process, so that was why rebooting helped in the short term, but getting the line fixed is what really did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. I had to turn off "Router mode" on the Netgear modem to prevent double NAT. In addition, I had a CAT5 cable from the modem to the router. Nobody mentioned that this could be a cause too. I changed this to CAT7 and it's much better now.

Comment: double nat should not cause the kind of problem you describe.

Comment: Also, CAT5 is capable of a maximum of 100Mbps